# D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(29168): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.Flutter:

Tags: flutter

I have a problem running my android flutter app.
Yesterday, my app ran successfully without any problem.
But today, whenever I try to run my app, it always gives me the next outputs and doesn't run.
The debug console keeps printing these :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on SM A405FN in debug mode...
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
D/FlutterActivity(29168): Using the launch theme as normal theme.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(29168): Setting up FlutterEngine.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(29168): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(29168): Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.
```

And weirdly, my app keeps stopping on my phone.

If you wonder about my `flutter doctor -v`, I can assure you that everything is fine.

```
[flutter] flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at /home/henimbola/dev_env/flutter
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (3 weeks ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /home/henimbola/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /home/henimbola/IDEs/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /home/henimbola/IDEs/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.2)
    • IntelliJ at /home/henimbola/IDEs/idea-IU-192.6603.28
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[✓] VS Code (version 1.42.1)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.8.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM A405FN • R58M66L8L9J • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
exit code 0
```

If anyone can help me please. I've been searching around the internet.

Answer (score 2):

This problem happened to me after I upgraded to the latest version of Flutter.
I solved it by running the command:

```
flutter clean
```

This has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**For proxy problems, follow these instructions!**

Add NO_PROXY with value 127.0.0.1 for your system variables.

[image]

Then, add for your gradle.properties the values **(YOUR_PROJECT/android/gradle.properties)**:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=localhost
systemProp.http.proxyPort=3128
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost
systemProp.https.proxyHost=localhost
systemProp.https.proxyPort=3128
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost
```

Now, close your IDE and Emulator/App and open them again.