# a problem when using shared preference's plugin

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I'm working on flutter and I've a problem with Shared preference plugin
this is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:newsapp/screens/homescreen.dart';
import 'package:newsapp/screens/onboarding.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
void  main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int seen1 = prefs.getInt('seen');
  Widget _screen = HomeScreen();
  if (seen1 == null || seen1 == 0)
    _screen = OnBoarding();
  else {
    _screen = HomeScreen();
  }

}
class NewsApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget _screen;
  NewsApp(this._screen);
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: this._screen,
    );
  }
}
```

this is the error messeage:

No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 1817): Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.
D/FlutterView( 1817): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@e2b1eab

Answer (score 0):

We need to add `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` before getting

```
await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

Like :

```
void  main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int seen1 = prefs.getInt('seen');
  Widget _screen = HomeScreen();
  if (seen1 == null || seen1 == 0)
    _screen = OnBoarding();
  else {
    _screen = HomeScreen();
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks but another problem showed:
the error says:
No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 1817): Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.
D/FlutterView( 1817): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@e2b1eab

Comment: I think flutter clean command should work. If you are still facing the issue, you can check out these links: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50882.  Second Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60466163/d-flutteractivityandfragmentdelegate29168-no-preferred-flutterengine-was-prov

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to end your `main()` method with `runApp(NewsApp());`
2. move your logic code from `main()` method to `NewsApp` widget.
3. convert your `NewsApp` widget to `StatefulWidget` to fitch your data from `SharedPreferences`.

like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:newsapp/screens/homescreen.dart';
import 'package:newsapp/screens/onboarding.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
void  main() {
   runApp(NewsApp());
}
class NewsApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _NewsAppState createState() => _NewsAppState();
}
class _NewsAppState extends State<NewsApp> {
  final Widget _screen = HomeScreen();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      int seen1 = prefs.getInt('seen');

      if (seen1 == null || seen1 == 0)
        _screen = OnBoarding();
      else {
        _screen = HomeScreen();
      }
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: this._screen,
    );
  }
}
```